# How to change the color of a path in a vector by group name

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a vector image with many various paths in groups. I want the color of the paths to change programmatically based on an input value. Is it possible to access the name parameter of the vector path? And then change the color.

```xml
<vector 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="350dp"
  android:height="320dp"
  android:viewportWidth="350"
  android:viewportHeight="320"
  android:name="vector_name">

  <group
    android:name="g1">
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
  </group>
  <group
    android:name="g2">
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
  </group>
  <group
    android:name="g3">
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
  </group>
  <group
    android:name="g4">
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
    <path
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:pathData="..."/>
  </group>
</vector>
```

Comment: If you need all groups to have same color then you can use setColorFilter property to set the color programatically

Comment: It not possible. you can tint Color, U can not possible to edit by code